# Intersection of neighborhoods of 0. Subgroup?

Tags: group-theory, commutative-algebra, topological-groups

Repeating for my exam in commutative algebra.

Let G be a topological abelian group, i.e. such that the mappings $+:G\times G \to G$ and $-:G\to G$ are continuous. Then we have the following Lemma:

Let H be the intersection of all neighborhoods of $0$ in $G$. Then $H$ is a subgroup.

The proof in the books is the following one-liner: "follows from continuity of the group operations". (this is from "Introduction to Commutative Algebra" by Atiyah-MacDonald)

I must admit that I don't really see how that "follows". If there is an easy explanation aimed at someone who has not encountered topological groups in any extent, I'd be happy to read it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $U$ is a neighbourhood of $0$ then so is $-U=\{-x:x\in U\}$.
This shows that if $x\in H$ then $-x\in H$.

To show that $H$ is closed under addition, use the fact that
if $U$ is a neighbourhood of $0$ then there is another
neighbourhood $V$ of $0$ with $V+V\subseteq U$. The existence
of $V$ follows from the continuity of addition at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Thanks. So since $+$ is continous, there exists a neighborhood $W \subset G\times G$ such that $+(W)\subseteq U$. Projecting $W$ down to $G$, we get our $V$. Is this correct?

Comment: Roughly speaking yes, you need that $W$ contains a set $V\times V$ where $V$ is a neighbourhood of $0$ in $G$.