# How to show that the intersection of all neighbourhood of $0$ in a topological group is a subgroup?

Tags: group-theory, topological-groups

Let $H$ be the intersection of all neighbourhood of $0$ in a topological group $G$. How to show that $H$ is a subgroup?

I tried to use the continuity of multiplication and inverse. But not successful. Thank you very much.

Edit: it seems that we need the condition that $G$ is abelian. If $G$ is not ablian, do we have $H$ is a subgroup?

Comment: I asked this question before. See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13368/intersection-of-neighborhoods-of-0-subgroup?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $U$ be any neighbourhood of $0$, then $\exists$ a neighbourhood $V$ of $0$ such that $VV^{-1} \subset U$ : Let $f: G\times G \to G$ be the map $(a,b) \mapsto ab^{-1}$. Then, $f^{-1}(U)$ is an open neighbourhood of $(0,0)$. Hence it contains a neighbourhood $V_1\times V_2$ of $(0,0)$. Now $V = V_1\cap V_2$ works.

Let $x,y\in H$, then for any neighbourhood $U$ containing $0$, choose $V$ as above. Then $x,y \in V$, so $xy^{-1} \in U$, and so $xy^{-1} \in H$.

Thus, $H$ is a subgroup.

Answer (score 1):

You're quite right, you do need the condition G is Abelian for this particular claim. Why isn't obvious,but your question's been asked before on here. Here's the answer and several versions of the proof.

[Intersection of all neighborhoods of zero is a subgroup](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174955/intersection-of-all-neighborhoods-of-zero-is-a-subgroup)

It's worth noting this turns out to be a special case of a more general result:

Theorem: If G is a topological group and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then the closure of $H$ in the topology $\bar {H}$ is also a subgroup in $G$.

Proof. Let $g,h \in\bar {H}$. Let U be an open neighborhood of the product $gh$. Let  $\mu:G \times G \rightarrow$ G denote the multiplication map, which is continuous, so $\mu^{-1}(U)$ is open in GxG, and contains $(g,h)$. So, there are open neighborhoods $V_1$ of $g$ and $V_2$ of $h$ such that $V_1 \times V_2\in\mu^{-1}(U)$. Since $g,h\in\bar {H}$, then there are points $x\in V_1\cap H \neq \emptyset$ and $y\in V_2\cap H  \neq \emptyset$. Thus, $x,y\in H$, we have $xy\in H$ and since $(x,y)\in \mu^{-1}(U)$ then $xy \in U$ Therefore $xy\in U\cap H$. Since $U$ was an arbitrary open neighborhood of gh, then we have $gh\in \bar{H}$. Now let $i:G \rightarrow G$ denote the inverse map, and let W be an open neighborhood of $h ^{1}$. Then $i^{-1}(W) = W^{-1}$ is open and contains h, so there is a point $z\in H\cap W^ {1}\neq \emptyset$. But this means $z^{-1}\in H\cap W\neq\emptyset$ and it implies $h^{-1}\in\bar{H}$. But this means $\bar{H}$ is a topological subgroup of G and we're done!

Note this result is perfectly general and covers the earlier claim as a special case. So the Abelian requirement isn't really needed!

Answer (score 0):

Let $a,b$ be in that intersection $H$. Then they are in every neighborhood of $e$. So you can easily check, that every open neighborhood of $a$ or $b$ is also a neighborhood of $e$ and vice versa (o/w apply map say $a^{-1}$). Similar you check that neighborhoods of $ab$ correspond to neighborhoods of $a$ (push everything back and forth by multiplication maps).